# OnModelCreating

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have three classes: `Address`, `User` and `Application`. Both `User` and `Application` have an address field.

User:

```
    [Required, ForeignKey("HomeAddress")]
    public int HomeAddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address HomeAddress { get; set; }
```

Application:

```
    [Required, ForeignKey("PresentAddress")]
    public int PresentAddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address PresentAddress { get; set; }
```

I am writing the following code to workaround the "cycles or multiple cascade paths" issue. I want to remove the cascade deletion for `Application`. Is the following code correct?

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Application>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.PresentAddress)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.PresentAddressId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

Comment: Looks OK, but we can't see if this causes any issues.

Comment: What's the `WithMany(...)`?